# Make SqlAlchemy put join result in separate classes

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I have a condition in which I have joined a table with itself. For getting result rows I need to have two separate attributes in the result rows each of which contain model items.

```
order_sq1: Order = self._query_from(Order). \
filter(Order.status == OrderStatus.REGISTERED.value,
       Order.dispatch_date + Order.dispatch_time > current_time,
       Order.who_added_role != UserRole.SHIPPER.value).subquery('Order1')

order_sq2: Order = self._query_from(Order). \
filter(Order.status == OrderStatus.REGISTERED.value,
       Order.dispatch_date + Order.dispatch_time > current_time,
       Order.who_added_role != UserRole.SHIPPER.value).subquery('Order2')

query = self._query_from(order_sq1).join(
order_sq2,
and_(order_sq1.c.tracking_code != order_sq2.c.tracking_code,
     func.ST_DistanceSphere(order_sq1.c.destination_location,
                            order_sq2.c.source_location) < 0.15 *
     order_sq1.c.distance
     , func.ST_DistanceSphere(order_sq2.c.destination_location,
                              order_sq1.c.source_location) < 0.15 *
     order_sq1.c.distance
     , between(((order_sq1.c.dispatch_date + order_sq1.c.dispatch_time) -
                (order_sq2.c.dispatch_date + order_sq2.c.dispatch_time) -
                (order_sq1.c.distance / 60) * timedelta(hours=1)),
               timedelta(hours=2),
               timedelta(hours=20))
     , order_sq1.c.source_region_id != order_sq1.c.destination_region_id
     , order_sq2.c.source_region_id != order_sq2.c.destination_region_id
     , order_sq1.c.vehicle_type == order_sq2.c.vehicle_type
     )).add_columns(order_sq2)
```

I need the result in the form of (Order1, Order2) fields, each as Order class.

I tried many ways with no success!

Comment: Subquery does not represent the ORM Class

Comment: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#selecting-entities-from-subqueries